# Can Stack Overflow have user IDs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I was just wondering: Can Stack Overflow` have user names?

Not the way the current system is, that is, some numeric ID. But in the way [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) or other sites have, like for example: `www.facebook.com/username`. So is it possible on Stack Overflow too?

Well, this can be a suggestion for developers too.

Because giving Stack Overflow's own usernames can increase enthusiasm and can help in sharing it on websites too.

Comment: On a side note, please don't use inline code spans (`like this`) for emphasis: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right/165710#165710

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since user names are **not unique**, no, this is not possible.

Comment: But They can generate unique names or even better they can ask user to pick one.

Comment: @VedantTerkar or even better, they can _not_ do that. SO is not facebook or any other social network.

Comment: What's the benefit for the site, @Vedant?

Comment: @Oded, Just like flairs, It can be used for mailing purposes too, like `mailto:username@so.com`

Comment: @l4mpi, But I use SO as programmers social network!

Comment: @VedantTerkar - we don't give out so.com emails either. Or have PMs. If you use SO as a social network for programmers, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @VedantTerkar that was never and should never be the intention of SO. You wouldn't use wikipedia as a social network either or would you?

Comment: Okay.This makes sense. You guys are right. Just one more question why the downvotes on my question(this question) didn't affected my reputation on meta?

Comment: You don't have reputation on meta. It is inherited from the main site (Stack Overflow in this case) and votes don't do anything to it. @Vedant.

Comment: @VedantTerkar - correct. You can read up about it in the [help center](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @l4mpi slow on the Wikipedia horses there :) WP core authors tend to organize in local chapters and meet up regularly, to do WP-related stuff like Photo sprees, visiting museums, or doing OSM-work. Example: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Dresden -- this could be called some kind of social networky thing which would not exist without WP

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu the same could be done with SE chat rooms - semi-regular events like tag cleanups and CV sprees all have a social aspect even though they happen online. But my point was simply that the core functionality of wikipedia, similar to the core functionality of SE, has nothing to do with being a social network as both are a knowledge base. Thus social features should not be introduced if one cannot make a strong case that they would improve this knowledge base. In case of SE, I think we can make a case that too many social features would make things worse.

Comment: @l4mpi Agreed. SO also lacks the free form permanence areas that personal wiki pages, portals and discussion pages offer on WP, so there's way fewer facilities to encourage networking. As for the OP request, introducing unique user names for email and user pages will also introduce a "market" to grab and possibly even trade "valuable" names. Like Odet and you said - what's the benefit.

Comment: If someone is proud of their SO internet points, perhaps a cleaner url is what the OP is getting at.